# Project doesnt run main class

Tags: java, jform-designer

I have a small problem with Jform-Designer, I've made a Designer class (Jform class) and i defined that as my main class.

Like this:

```
class Designer extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Designer design;
        design = new Designer();
        design.initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents


        //======== this ========
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FormLayout(
            "9*(default, $lcgap), default",
            "9*(default, $lgap), default"));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }
}
```

But the program doesnt run now, i think it is stuck in a infinite loop at this part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Designer design;
            design = new Designer();
            design.initComponents();
        }
```

Can someone explain what i need to do to run the project properly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well what makes you think it's stuck in a loop? (I don't see a loop there.) What happens when you try to run it? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've tried debugging it but didnt find anything but the problem is already solved.

Comment: how can it be stuck in an infinite loop if it doesn't run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs but you're not making the frame visible

```
design.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I also recommend using `design.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`; so program wil actually exit after closing window